# How do I call FlatFileItemReader multiple times with different file names in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Goal: Have one file reader that can be called from 1 to N times, with different file names in Spring batch without have to close/reopen files every read.

What I have so far:

I roughed out the program using the following bean for reading the CSV files:

```
@Bean
    public ItemReader<DataLoadRecordClass> dataLoadFileItemReader() {
        this.inputRecords = new DataLoadRecordListClass();
        FlatFileItemReader<DataLoadRecordClass> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<DataLoadRecordClass>();
        reader.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1); //skip header line
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(String.format(this.fileSystemBasePath,storeName) + this.fileBasePath + this.inFileName));
        LineMapper<DataLoadRecordClass> dataFileLineMapper = buildLineMapper();
        reader.setLineMapper(dataFileLineMapper);
        return reader;
    }
```

StoreName and inFileName will be specified at run time, and there will normally be at least 4 stores this will need to be run for, but the requirements are for it to run for 1 to N stores.

Obviously, as the code is written it will only work for 1 store and 1 file. How can I scale this so that it can run for 1 to N stores with 1 to N files in each store, and in parallel? I do not want to create beans for each possible store and file obviously since the only difference in them will be the file name and path.

Thanks!

Comment: look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html

Comment: Thanks, but every example I find of that still has the reader looking at some set file name/path, even if it has a wild card. I need it to be able to take the file name/path in at runtime and run each file side by side in parallel through essentially the same steps.

Comment: Just make the bean `@StepScope` then inject a variable from the `jobParameters` so that you can parameterize your job.

Comment: Can you link an example of how to do that? I can not find an example of how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allows me to pass in variables

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<DataLoadRecordClass> dataLoadFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['myParam']}" String storeNameEntry) {  
..etc..
}
```

The big catch was you can not use ItemReader for this, you have to return the FlatFileItemReader or you will get an error that it can not open the reader. This only happened with StepScope.